# Datacontext in LINQ. "Does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq-to-sql

I keep on receiving this error message. I followed the instructions but it seems it is still not working? what is the solution for this? here's my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyDatabaseDataContext = new MyDatabaseDataContext(@"C:\Users\John\Documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\MyDatabase.mdf");
        }


    }
}
```

Here's the stacktrace

```
Error   1   'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'Form1_Load' and no extension method 'Form1_Load' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.Designer.cs 92  55  WindowsFormsApplication1
```

Comment: Can you post a complete stack trace.

Comment: What was generated in InitializeComponent?  What exception are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens if you add an event handler in the designer, then delete the handler method.
Since you didn't delete the auto-generated code that adds the method to the event, you get a compiler error.

Go to the `.Designer.cs` file and delete the line with the error.